# How can i give permission to a folder in windows server IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm a PHP and windows Server newbie and I'm getting the following error when viewing a form that I created in PHP.

```
Error in exception handler: The stream or file "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wrp\app\storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wrp\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:84
```

I'm on a Windows 2008 Server R1 (64bit) running IIS 7 and PHP through Fast CGI. Except for this issue PHP is running fine on the server. I'm running PHPMyAdmin and a couple other PHP apps just fine. I confirmed that I have permissions set correctly (have even run php files at the directory and file level under full control to test)

Appreciate any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue. Also, are you aware of any forums or community sites geared just for those running PHP under FastCG on IIS 7?

Comment: Your code will run with the access rights of the application pool host process identity, so you should check the filesystem permissions of your problem folder and make sure the application pool account has access to the file mentioned in your error message. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa954062.aspx) for more details.

Comment: how can i give the access for the folder ?

Comment: Just through Windows Explorer - right-click, properties, security.

Comment: i did that but still not working getting the same error

Comment: Does the account have access to the full path? You can have access to a file but still be unable to get to the directory in which it's located...

Comment: If you're still stuck, [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) logs all file access requests, and may help you track down your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2

When a file or folder is created, Windows assigns default permissions to that object.

**Modify** is the minimum permission required to complete this procedure. Review the details in "Additional considerations" in this topic.

To set, view, change, or remove permissions on files and folders

1. Right-click the file or folder for which you want to set permissions, click **Properties**, and then click the **Security tab.**
2. Click **Edit** to open the **Permissions for**  dialog box.
3. Do one of the following:

   - To set permissions for a group or user that does not appear in the Group or user names box, click Add. Type the name of the group or user you want to set permissions for, and then click OK.
   - To change or remove permissions from an existing group or user, click the name of the group or user.
4. Do one of the following:

   - To allow or deny a permission, in the Permissions for  box, select the Allow or Deny check box.
   - To remove the group or user from the Group or user names box, click Remove.