# Laravel + ISS Server + Failed Request Log

Tags: laravel, iis, laravel-5, iis-7.5, laravel-5.3

When i using Laravel application (5.2/5.3) in a IIS Server the Failed Request Log cant capture errors throwed inside Laravel.

Example, i put in my Rule to track errors 404 and 500. I entered at website in a not existing route. In chrome inspect i see the 404 error at response, but IIS dont created the file of this error.

Another case: if i force an error 500 - echoing a undefined variable - the log cannot tracked. But if i repeat the process in a isolated .php file (without laravel) the error is tracked.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise the errors generated by a Laravel application are stored in the storage/logs directory.

Comment: Not in this case, unfortunately

Comment: Strange that, it was to stay in the IIS logs or the Laravel application.

Comment: I've solved this case. I've found a try/catch block, because of this the error was not are in laravel.log, but the iis continues not  capturing fails requests.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.3 monolog is used as the logging driver. Perhaps certain permission are not properly set on that type of server.

I have found a similar question/answer that my help you solve this problem.

[How can i give permission to a folder in windows server IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159380/how-can-i-give-permission-to-a-folder-in-windows-server-iis-7)